# Call activity after ends a call

Tags: android, telephonymanager

In my application i want to call activity when i ends the call. The person has to attend the call and once he had a conversation then he will ends the call. Here i want to call the activity when the person ends the call. I don't want to call the activity in idle state. After he ends the call then the callReceived goes to false and callEnded goes to true. I can't view my activity once the call ends.Please give me an idea to achieve this scenario. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code.

```
public static boolean ring=false;
public static boolean callReceived=false;
public static boolean callEnded=false;
public void telephonyRegister(Context context, Intent intent)
{
 String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);                         
 ctx=context;
 if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
         TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {  
     callEnded =true;
     if(ring==true&&callReceived==false)
     {
         Toast.makeText(context, "THIS IS MISSED CALL FROM"+phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         String smsmessage = "We will contact you shortly";
         SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
         smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, "Hi"+" "+smsmessage, null, null);
         Log.i("sms",smsmessage);
         Toast.makeText(context, "SMS sent.",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
     }
     Toast.makeText(context,"Recording Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     stopRecording();


    }
 else if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
         TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
 {
     callReceived = true;
     Toast.makeText(context,"Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     callEnded =false;
     if(callReceived==false&&callEnded==true)
     {
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(ctx, PushRemarkstoServer.class);  
         ctx.startActivity(myIntent);

     }
 }
 else if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
         TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
     ring = true;
     phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("incoming_number");        
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() { 
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,ProjectDailogActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("incoming_number",phoneNumber);
             intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             ctx.startActivity(intent);

         }
     }, 2000);  

 }
 else
 {

 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, when the phone rings assign callringing as true and if picked and if call was incoming then set call_attended as true. Later after the incoming call is disconnected and if call_attended is true then start your activity. Rough code below:

```
String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
iscallringing=true;
}
else if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK&&iscallringing){
call_attended=true;
iscallringing=false;
}
else if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE&&call_attended){
//start your activity here
call_attended=false;
iscallringing=false;
}
```

Comment: Did you declare these iscallringing, call_attended as global varible. Try putting logs in each of the if statement to know what is the value of these variable during the phone call phases